# how to update magical record sdk in pod file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I want to update magical record from 2.2 to 2.3.3 sdk. In my project having pod file.. so how to update magical record sdk 2.2 to magical record 2.3.3 sdk. please guide me any body.i am new to cocoa pods and pod file. Thanks in advance. in my pod file having like this

pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.2'

pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1.1'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.2'

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'

This is the magical record sdk 2.3.3 updated link.
https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Open Terminal

2) Write **CD** command. and Drag and Drop folder (To get a path of your project) -> press enter

3) write command **open -e podfile** (to add a new version)

4) close podfile . write command in terminal **pod upade**

That's it.

**Edit 1 :-**

[image]

Edit 2 :-

Step 1 :- Remove "pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.3.3’ " from your pod file.

step 2:- pod update (it will uninstall magical record from your project)

Now again follow edit 1 as write again **"pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.3.3’ "** in your podfile.  and write command pod update.

Edit 3 :- Don't forget open your project from **.xcworkspace** file.

[image]

**Note :-** Before do anything first take backup of your project.

Comment: plz give me step by step guidelines how to do this thing. why because i am entirely new to cocoapods and pod file

Comment: excellent bro.. thank u so much i will try it now.. plz don't remove your answer

Comment: yes . as well as i have also update my answer step by step.

Comment: I can't understand ?

Comment: in terminal displaying like this after update pod file..Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `MagicalRecord (~> 2.3.3)` required by `Podfile`

Comment: in pod file displaying like this  "pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.3.3’
"

Comment: wait . try as i say.

Comment: i got these type of issues also in my Xcode "clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Reachability/Pods-Reachability-dummy.m'"

Comment: I updated answer. try edit 2. and don't forget to open project from workspace. do you have demo ?

Comment: hi bro now i got this issue "diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
"

Comment: you there plz guide me bro

Comment: @subbu sorry i am on way to home. are you there ?

Comment: Shal yes tell me bro. yesterday i was on leave.. till know i can't fix the issues..

Comment: yes bro. plz come to chat.. i want to fix this issue by the end of the day.. plz come to stack overflow chat

Comment: Shal can you create chat room.??

Comment: don't know why auomatically chat option not come.

Comment: in stack overflow plz come this chat room "Telugu Mobile Developers (iOS and Android)"

Comment: i am available on that room.

Answer (score 0):

replace `pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.2'` with `pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.3'`

and then

1. open terminal
2. type cd -> Drag and drop your projectfolder

   pod install

Comment: thanks for your response if i did like this the magical record should be updated in my entire project??

Comment: plz give me step by step guidelines how to do this thing. why because i am entirely new to cocoapods and pod file